# Почему метод Character.toLowerCase() игнорируется?

Tags: java

Поясните пожалуйста почему метод Character.toLowerCase() игнорируется и как правильно написать программу в таком подходе решения данной задачи без указания гласных в верхнем регистре во втором методе?
При написании этой программы в IDE получаю предупрждение "Result of 'Character.toLowerCase()' is ignored".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
        Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        return Character.toString(ch).matches("[aeiou]");
    }

    /* Do not change code below */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char letter = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(isVowel(letter) ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Игнорируется потому что Вы игнорируете полученный результат. `Character` это [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) тип, что значит, что созданный экземпляр изменить нельзя. Соответственно, `Character.toLowerCase(ch)` не меняет `ch`, а **возвращает** `ch` в нижнем регистре.
Пара вариантов, как исправить:

1.

```java
Character.toLowerCase(ch);
```

заменить на

```java
ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
```

---

2. 

```java
Character.toLowerCase(ch);
return Character.toString(ch).matches("[aeiou]");
```

заменить на

```java
return Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(ch)).matches("[aeiou]");
```

---

3. 

```java
Character.toLowerCase(ch);
return Character.toString(ch).matches("[aeiou]");
```

заменить на

```java
return Character.toString(ch).matches("(?i)[aeiou]");
```

`matches("(?i)[aeiou]")` - проверка совпадения без учёта регистра.

Comment: Михаил, большое спасибо!